# Unexpected Intellij Auto Complete Results

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hey there basically I'm seeing unexpected auto completion by intellij. I have tried multiple way to get it to work the way I expected it to and can't.

https://www.webmshare.com/play/yAPxo

The first line is what happens when you press tab to auto complete something and the following is when you click it in the menu.

I was wondering if it is possible to change the behavior so when I press it TAB it follows the behavior of the second line.

Thanks.

Comment: Enter is the key for what you click in the menu to autoComplete. Tab replaces the remaining part, whereas enter just adds the completion into where the caret is. You should be able to change keys for those actions. I can't see your image btw. It is blocked where i work, I hope i guessed correctly.

Comment: This default random auto completion can be override by setting in - Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion, unchecking "Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc." Please check the answer below with screenshot.

Comment: @halil You are correct!, thank you a lot. It seems I'll just change the keys around.

Comment: Your video doesn't show the actual completion popup. What's the problem? The order of suggested elements?

Answer (score 0):

I came from work, I am glad it worked for you, so I wanted to add it as an answer.

Enter is the key for what you click in the menu to autoComplete. Tab replaces the remaining part, whereas enter just adds the completion into where the caret is. You should be able to change keys for those actions. To change those keys:

1. Open preferences in Intellij and go to Keymap
2. Change `Choose Lookup Item` with whichever key you want to use (it is `tab` key in your case I presume)